# Enthought canopy validation error

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x, canopy

I need help!!
I've been struggling with this problem and I cannot seem to solve it.

```
def itemName():
    flag = True
        while flag == True:
        try:
            name = input('What would You like to name it? \n')
            Input = str(Input)
            print(name)
            if name.upper() == ('BOAT') or name.upper() == ('CASUALTY'):
                flag = False
            else:
                raise Exception
        except:
            print('Boat or Casualty only')
    return name

name = itemName()
print(name)
```

This code will not pass when run. This works in the normal python IDLE but not canopy. Also the print statement only outputs if the input is an integer. I'm stumped, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is python 3 code. Canopy uses Python 2.7

The input function differs between these versions.

In python 2.7, the equivalent is `raw_input`

Comment: You can select Python 3 as a language though (which I have) - Oh and the same code works for other variables in the code this is part of

Comment: My original answer stands and is correct. Perhaps you are referring to the "file type" dropdown in the code editor, which offers "Python 3 traceback" as one option. That is completely unrelated. You can also select Fortran, but that doesn't mean that Canopy can run Fortran code.

Comment: As for "the same code works for other variables in the code this is part of"... you'll have to be much more precise if you want to get a helpful response to help you understand the problem. Bottom line, you are not going to be able to run Python 3 code in the current version of Canopy unless it is also written to be Python 2-compatible.

Comment: Finally, if you actually want to learn more about writing code that can be run in both Python 2 and Python 3, there are many resources. Some of these resources are linked here: https://support.enthought.com/entries/22119894-Preparing-for-Python-3-Now